# how to create nlog.config file in the user specified locations?

Tags: c#, nlog

how to create nlog.config file in the user specified locations to get the log files.

I am trying to create log file in the user specified location . 
But The Nlog checks for its Config file before writing into the user directory. 
so how to go about this issue ?

Comment: so does NLog overwrite what you create ?

Comment: Nevermind looks like someone else helped

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in code. Do something like this (*edited to include the rule as well*):

```
var userDefinedName = @"C:\TEMP\UserName\MyLogs\MyLogFile.txt";
var userFileTarget = new FileTarget {
    FileName = userDefinedName
};
var rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, userFileTarget);
Logger.Factory.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
```

There's other properties you can configure as well, but this illustrates how to modify the file location in code.

Comment: ya I think u r write . But the code in Nlog checks for config file in the particular folder to weite log files. so Now I must look for a way to make the config file to be copied to the particular location ? any help plz?

Comment: @judithnisha Have you tried this? It should override settings in your `nlog.config` file.

Comment: ya i did but it not changing  the path.

Comment: base {NLog.Targets.Target} = {File Target[(unnamed)]} thats the value of the target file name in rule